# Push a slightly changed string in JSON while condition is true

Tags: javascript, json

at first I am sorry for the title of the question. It might be misleading, but I dont know how to describe it briefly. I will try now:

I have long string of JSON format with many data. But I pick only some data of that depending on conditions.

The string could look like this (I have shortened it, but it is still kind of long):

```
var productItem = '{ "capacity": { "item": "130344", "billable": true }, "capacity_based_on_model": { "s": { "item": "131776", "billable": true }, "m": { "item": "131779", "billable": true }, "l": { "item": "131780", "billable": true }, "lo1": { "item": "131777", "billable": true }, "lo2": { "item": "131778", "billable": true } }, "os_license": { "Windows": { "item": "126944", "billable": true }, "Linux": { "item": "119690", "billable": true } }, "datacenter": { "Finland": { "item": "125524", "billable": false, "project": "124256", "task": "5" }, "Sweden": { "item": "125525", "billable": false, "project": "124256", "task": "5" } }, "os_24/7": { "Windows": { "item": "119590", "billable": true }, "Linux": { "item": "124399", "billable": true } }, "os": { "Windows": [ { "item": "119132", "billable": false, "project": "124336", "task": "3.2" }, { "item": "119133", "billable": false, "project": "124336", "task": "3.2" }, { "item": "125508", "billable": false, "project": "124336", "task": "3.2" }, { "item": "119589", "billable": true }, { "item": "120854", "billable": true }, { "item": "125125", "billable": true }, { "item": "126768", "billable": true } ], "Linux": [ { "item": "119132", "billable": false, "project": "164443", "task": "3.2" }, { "item": "119133", "billable": false, "project": "164443", "task": "3.2" }, { "item": "125508", "billable": false, "project": "164443", "task": "3.2" }, { "item": "120854", "billable": true }, { "item": "124398", "billable": true }, { "item": "125125", "billable": true }, { "item": "126768", "billable": true } ] } }';
```

Now, I am building a JSON from it. For example:

```
var productItemObject = {};
    productItemObject["productItemArray"] = [];
    productItemObject["productItemArray"].push(productItem["capacity"]);
    productItemObject["productItemArray"].push(productItem["capacity_based_on_model"]["s"]);
```

Some of parts are added under a condition (so the row below is not always triggered), like this:

```
productItemObject["productItemArray"].push(productItem["os_24/7"]["Windows"]);
```

Then, I have a for loop, which I use to add all items, depending on Windows or Linux.

```
for (var i in productItem["os"][osType]) {
                productItemObject["productItemArray"].push(productItem["os"]["Windows"][i]);
            }
```

Hope you understand, what I try to achieve by this. Now for the funny part I am stucked with right now:

If the row before the for loop (os_24/7) is triggered, which means that in the productItemObject, I will have

```
{ "item": "119590", "billable": true }
```

I would need to change one of the JSON added by the for loop. Specifically this one

```
{ "item": "119589", "billable": true }
```

I need to change the billable key to false, and then add it to array.

In short, everytime there is an item with value of 119590, I need to do a change to JSON with item 119589, billable to false. Other way (if there won't be item with value of 119590) the JSON with item 119589 will remain with billable on true.

I don't want to mess up the question more, so I'll stop here. Do you have any hint how to do that? Thank you

Comment: Are `{ "item": "119590", "billable": true }` and `{ "item": "119589", "billable": true }` saved to a variable? Or appended to something directly? Try saving to a variable and modifying before appending.

Comment: Both are saved to the variable productItem. The first item (119590) is not always presented, the second one is always there.

Comment: You are going to have to produce a Minimum Viable Example for us to understand what you are trying to achieve. You can use something like [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/dashboard) to do it.